# Regex for Transformations (without using multiple statements)

Tags: python, regex, pandas

What is the best way to use Regex to extract and transform one statement to another?

Specifically, I have implemented the below to find and extract a sudent number from a block of text and transform it as follows: *AB123CD* to *AB-123-CD*

Right now, this is implemented as 3 statements as follows:

```
gg['student_num'] = gg['student_test'].str.extract('(\d{2})\w{3}\d{2}') + \
                    '-' + gg['student_num'].str.extract('\d{2}(\w{3})\d{2}') + \
                    '-' + gg['student_test'].str.extract('\d{2}\w{3}(\d{2})')
```

It doesn't feel right to me that I would need to have three statements -
 one for each group - concatenated together below (or even more if this was more complicated) and wondered if there was a better way to find and transform some text?

Comment: Try `gg['student_num'] = gg['student_test'].str.replace(r'(\w{2})(\d{3})(\w{2})', r'\1-\2-\3')`. Well, it is not clear what column the data is in, just try the `replace` thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get list of segments using regexp and then join them this way:

```
'-'.join(re.search(r'(\d{2})(\w{3})(\d{2})', string).groups())
```

You could get `AttributeError` if `string` doesn't contain needed pattern (`re.search()` returns `None`), so you might want to wrap this expression in `try...except` block.

Comment: This is great, didn't realize that groups come out like an ordered list. Very Pythonic.

Comment: Exactly, it returns a tuple of matched groups.

Answer (score 1):

This is not regex, but it is quick and concise:

```
s = "AB123CD"

first = [i for i, a in enumerate(s) if a.isdigit()][0]
second = [i for i, a in enumerate(s) if a.isdigit()][-1]

new_form = s[:first]+"-"+s[first:second+1]+"-"+s[second+1:]
```

Output:

```
AB-123-CD
```

Alternative regex solution:

```
letters = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", s)
numbers = re.findall("[0-9]+", s)
letters.insert(1, numbers[0])
final = '-'.join(letters)
print(final)
```

Output:

```
AB-123-CD
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope that helps

```
>>> import re
>>> s = r'ABC123DEF'
>>> n = re.search(r'\d+',s).group()
>>> f  = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+',s)
>>> new_s = f[0]+"-"+n+"-"+f[1]
>>> new_s
```

Output:

```
'ABC-123-DEF'
```